# Behaviour of $u_{n}=\frac{u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}+n}{\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $u_1=u_2=1$ and
$$u_{n}=\frac{u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}+n}{\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)}$$
Then I suspect that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
which is equivalent to the fact that $\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)=1$ for $n$ large enough.

It seems that this property holds for any starting integer values $(u_1,u_2)$. Does anyone see how to prove it?

Proof of the equivalence. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\phi$ and since we have $\frac{n}{u_{n-1}}\rightarrow0$ then we get

$$\frac{1+\frac{u_{n-2}}{u_{n-1}}+\frac{n}{u_{n-1}}}{\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)} \sim\frac{1}{\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\varPhi}\right)\sim\varPhi\ \left(n\rightarrow\infty\right)$$

and necessarily we have $\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)\rightarrow1$. Since it is an integer value it must be $1$ for $n$ large enough.

In the other way if $\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)=1$ for $n>n_{0}$ then we have for $n>n_{0}$

$$u_{n}=u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}+n$$

and $u_{n}=a\varPhi^{n}+b\varPhi^{-n}+cn+d$ for some constants $(a,b,c,d)$ with $a>0$.

I add that if we replace $n$ with a function $f(n)$ sufficiently regular like $f(n)=n^2$  i.e.  $u_{n}=\frac{u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}+f(n)}{\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},f(n)\right)}$ the property seems to persist.

Thank you

ps: here the values of $n$ such that $\gcd\left(u_{n},u_{n-1},n+1\right)>1$ and the corresponding gcd. No gcd>1 after $n=22933$ until $n=10^6$

(5,5),(6,2),(9,3),(12,2),(27,3),(48,3),(69,3),(90,3),(111,3),(135,3),(159,3),(165,3),(171,3),(177,3),(183,3),(204,3),(225,3),(249,3),(270,3),(273,7),(291,3),(300,5),(306,17),(327,3),(333,3),(357,21),(363,3),(369,3),(393,3),(399,3),(420,3),(426,3),(430,5),(447,3),(471,3),(495,3),(519,3),(525,3),(546,3),(570,3),(594,9),(618,3),(624,3),(645,3),(669,3),(690,3),(714,3),(738,3),(744,3),(750,15),(771,3),(777,3),(801,3),(807,3),(820,5),(834,3),(840,3),(864,3),(885,3),(891,3),(897,3),(903,3),(924,3),(945,3),(951,3),(960,5),(972,9),(993,3),(1017,3),(1038,3),(1059,3),(1075,5),(1080,3),(1095,5),(1116,3),(1122,3),(1143,9),(1167,3),(1191,3),(1212,3),(1236,3),(1242,3),(1248,3),(1260,5),(1278,3),(1280,5),(1358,7),(1428,7),(1444,19),(16781,173),(16800,3),(16806,3),(16808,11),(16814,7),(16830,15),(16836,3),(16857,3),(16863,3),(16870,5),(16890,3),(16911,3),(16932,3),(16953,3),(16977,3),(17001,3),(17007,3),(17028,33),(17034,3),(17050,5),(17055,3),(17061,3),(17067,3),(17073,3),(17079,3),(17103,3),(17109,3),(17130,3),(17136,9),(17160,3),(17166,3),(17175,5),(17178,7),(17187,3),(17195,5),(17208,3),(17220,5),(17221,17),(17241,3),(17262,3),(17286,3),(17300,5),(17304,3),(17325,3),(17331,3),(17355,3),(17376,3),(17400,3),(17424,3),(17445,3),(17466,3),(17487,3),(17511,3),(17532,3),(17538,3),(17544,3),(17550,3),(17556,3),(17562,3),(17586,9),(17610,3),(17616,3),(17622,3),(17628,3),(17633,7),(17652,3),(17673,3),(17685,5),(17697,3),(17718,3),(17725,5),(17733,3),(17754,3),(17766,7),(17775,3),(17790,5),(17810,5),(17811,3),(17835,3),(17856,3),(17862,3),(17868,3),(17892,3),(17898,3),(17919,3),(17940,3),(17961,3),(17967,3),(17988,3),(17994,3),(18015,3),(18039,3),(18063,3),(18081,7),(18084,3),(18108,3),(18125,5),(18132,3),(18138,3),(18162,3),(18164,19),(18168,3),(18189,3),(18195,3),(18201,3),(18225,3),(18249,3),(18273,3),(18279,3),(18300,3),(18321,3),(18340,7),(18342,3),(18348,3),(18354,3),(18368,7),(18378,3),(18402,3),(18408,3),(18414,3),(18435,3),(18441,3),(18465,3),(18471,3),(18480,5),(18492,3),(18498,3),(18515,5),(18522,3),(18528,3),(18535,5),(18555,3),(18561,3),(18565,5),(18582,3),(18606,3),(18615,5),(18618,3),(18642,3),(18648,3),(18654,3),(18660,3),(18681,3),(18702,3),(18723,3),(18729,3),(18750,3),(18774,9),(18798,3),(18810,5),(18828,3),(18849,3),(18870,3),(18876,3),(18882,3),(18906,3),(18912,3),(18918,3),(18924,3),(18928,7),(18948,3),(18972,3),(18978,3),(18999,3),(19020,3),(19026,9),(19032,3),(19038,3),(19059,3),(19080,3),(19086,3),(19103,7),(19110,3),(19115,5),(19128,3),(19134,3),(19140,3),(19164,3),(19170,3),(19176,3),(19182,3),(19206,9),(19227,3),(19248,3),(19254,3),(19275,3),(19285,7),(19296,3),(19320,3),(19341,3),(19347,3),(19353,3),(19359,3),(19360,5),(19365,3),(19386,3),(19392,3),(19413,3),(19419,3),(19425,3),(19446,3),(19467,3),(19473,3),(19479,3),(19485,3),(19506,3),(19515,5),(19527,3),(19548,3),(19558,7),(19569,3),(19575,3),(19596,3),(19602,3),(19626,3),(19635,11),(19647,3),(19653,3),(19659,3),(19665,3),(19669,13),(19671,3),(19677,3),(19698,3),(19715,5),(19725,3),(19746,3),(19752,3),(19776,3),(19782,3),(19788,3),(19809,3),(19830,3),(19851,3),(19872,3),(19896,3),(19920,3),(19935,5),(19953,3),(19959,3),(19965,5),(19968,3),(19989,3),(20013,3),(20034,3),(20058,3),(20064,3),(20085,3),(20106,3),(20125,5),(20127,3),(20148,3),(20154,3),(20175,3),(20199,3),(20220,3),(20244,3),(20268,3),(20274,3),(20295,3),(20316,3),(20322,3),(20328,3),(20334,3),(20355,3),(20376,3),(20382,3),(20390,5),(20406,3),(20412,3),(20418,3),(20442,3),(20460,11),(20481,3),(20487,3),(20493,3),(20499,3),(20523,3),(20544,3),(20550,3),(20571,3),(20577,3),(20583,3),(20604,3),(20610,3),(20634,3),(20658,3),(20679,3),(20700,3),(20721,3),(20727,3),(20748,3),(20769,3),(20790,9),(20796,3),(20817,3),(20838,3),(20846,7),(20862,3),(20883,3),(20907,3),(20913,3),(20919,3),(20925,5),(20928,3),(20952,3),(20958,3),(20982,3),(21006,3),(21020,5),(21027,3),(21028,7),(21035,5),(21048,3),(21054,3),(21060,3),(21084,21),(21105,3),(21129,3),(21153,3),(21159,3),(21165,3),(21171,3),(21192,3),(21213,3),(21230,5),(21237,3),(21243,3),(21264,3),(21270,15),(21291,3),(21312,3),(21333,3),(21339,9),(21345,3),(21351,3),(21357,3),(21378,3),(21399,21),(21420,3),(21425,5),(21438,3),(21462,3),(21476,7),(21483,3),(21500,5),(21510,3),(21534,3),(21555,3),(21576,3),(21595,7),(21597,3),(21621,3),(21630,7),(21642,3),(21648,3),(21654,3),(21660,3),(21665,5),(21666,3),(21687,3),(21708,3),(21714,3),(21720,3),(21725,5),(21735,23),(21750,3),(21756,3),(21762,3),(21783,3),(21807,3),(21828,3),(21852,3),(21876,3),(21880,5),(21900,3),(21924,3),(21930,3),(21945,11),(21963,3),(21984,3),(21990,3),(22005,5),(22026,3),(22047,3),(22071,3),(22077,3),(22083,3),(22089,3),(22100,5),(22104,3),(22125,3),(22146,3),(22170,3),(22180,5),(22191,3),(22197,3),(22203,3),(22209,3),(22220,5),(22224,3),(22245,3),(22269,3),(22280,5),(22284,3),(22305,3),(22326,3),(22332,3),(22341,11),(22353,3),(22359,3),(22365,9),(22386,3),(22407,3),(22417,29),(22428,9),(22434,3),(22435,7),(22455,3),(22461,3),(22467,3),(22473,3),(22494,3),(22500,3),(22521,3),(22527,3),(22535,5),(22548,3),(22554,7),(22572,3),(22593,3),(22603,7),(22614,3),(22638,3),(22659,3),(22680,3),(22686,3),(22710,3),(22734,3),(22755,3),(22765,5),(22776,3),(22797,3),(22821,3),(22827,7),(22835,5),(22842,3),(22848,3),(22855,5),(22875,3),(22880,11),(22932,7)

Comment: Why did you say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is equivalent to  $\gcd\left(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n\right)=1$ for $n$ large enough

Comment: I put the answer in my question

Comment: Can you give some numerical simulations that consolidate your prediction

Comment: Of course. I added the values of $n$ such that $\gcd\left(u_{n},u_{n-1},n+1\right)>1$

Comment: We must have $u_{n} = \lambda F_{n} + \mu F_{n+1}-n-3$ for some fixed constants $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{Z}$ for sufficiently large $n$ If $\text{gcd}(u_{m-1}, u_{m-2}, m) = 1$ for large $m$.

Answer (score 3):

### The property probably does not hold.

An argument can be made that the property is unlikely to hold. Define $d_n = \gcd(u_{n-1},u_{n-2},n)$, $d_{\infty}=1$ and pick $N$ s.t. $d_{N-1} = 1$. Let $M$ be the smallest integer such that $d_{M} \neq 1, M\geq N$ or $M=+\infty$ if no such integer exists. For $n=N$ define
$$a_n = 2 + 3n/2 + u_{n-2} + u_{n-1}/2,\\
b_n = 1 + n/2 + u_{n-1}/2. \tag{1}$$
We assume that the numbers $a_n$ and $b_n$ are integers with even $a_n + b_n$. For $u_1=u_2=1$ this assumption holds starting from $n=14$; if it does not hold, we can check that $2$ will divide $d_n$ within 6 iterations.

For $n>N$ define $a_n$ and $b_n$ by the recursive relation
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\b_{n}\end{pmatrix} =
\frac12 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{n-1}\\b_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.\tag{2}$$
It is easy to check that then equations (1) hold for $N \leq n \leq M$ and not only for $n=N$. Define

$$\widetilde{d}_n = \gcd(a_n-2, b_n-1). \tag{3}$$

**Lemma 1.**

1. If $p \mid d_M, p\notin \{2\}$ then $p \mid \widetilde{d}_n$,
2. If $p \mid \widetilde{d}_n, p\notin \{2,5\}$ then $M < \infty$.

Proof. #1 follows from $p\mid n$, $p\mid u_{n-1}$, $p\mid u_{n-2}$ and the formulas (1).

To prove #2 assume the contrary: $M=\infty$. Then (1) hold for all $n\geq N$. Define the field $F$ by $F=\text{GF}(p)$ when $\sqrt{5} \in \text{GF}(p)$ (i.e. when $p\equiv\pm 1 \mod 5$) and $F=\text{GF}(p)[\sqrt{5}]$ otherwise. In both cases $u_{\pm} = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} \in F$. Define $v_{\pm} = \frac{a_{N} \pm b_{N}\sqrt{5}}{2 \pm \sqrt{5}}\in F$. Let $\text{order}(u_{\pm})$ be the multiplicative order of $u_{\pm}$. It divides $p^2-1$ and, hence,
$\text{lcm}_{\pm}(\text{order}(u_{\pm}))$ is coprime with $p$. We have $p\mid \widetilde d_n$ iff $u_{\pm}^{n-N}v_{\pm} = 1$ for both choices of $\pm$. If $n_0$ is the first such integer, then for $n=n_0+k\;\text{lcm}_{\pm}(\text{order}(u_{\pm}))$ also satisfies $p\mid \widetilde d_n$ for any non-negative integer $k$. Since $\text{lcm}_{\pm}(\text{order}(u_{\pm}))$ is coprime with $p$ we can pick $k$ such that $p\mid n_0 + k\;\text{lcm}_{\pm}(\text{order}(u_{\pm}))$. Then $p\mid d_n$.$\;\;\square$

Let's now estimate the likelihood that there is no $p,n$ s.t. $p\mid \widetilde d_{n}, p \notin \{2,5\}$ (which is required from Lemma 1 for $M=\infty$).

**Conjecture 1.** There is a positive density of primes $p$ s.t. $r \geq p-1$, where $r = \gcd_{\pm}(\text{order}(u_{\pm}))$.

Note 1.1. For $p\equiv \pm 1\mod 5$ we have $r\mid (p-1)$. For $p \equiv \pm2 \mod 5$ we have $r\mid (2p+2)$. Indeed

$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{p} = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},$$
$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{p+1} = -1,$$
$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2p+2} = 1.$$

Thus, the condition $r \geq p-1$ is equivalent to $r=p-1$ when $p\equiv \pm 1\mod 5$ and $r=2p+2$ when $p\equiv \pm2\mod5$.

Note 1.2. If one were to try to prove conjecture 1, methods in [Kurlberg, Pomerance "On a problem of Arnold: The average multiplicative order of a given integer"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/algebra-and-number-theory/volume-7/issue-4/On-a-problem-of-Arnold--The-average-multiplicative-order/10.2140/ant.2013.7.981.pdf) could be useful. There is a related open problem ["Artin's conjecture on primitive roots"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots).

---

**Non-rigorous speculation part**

There is no easy way to talk about likelihoods of mathematical statements. In most cases they are either true or false. E.g. we can say that the probability the digit $9$ occurs more than $10^5$ times in the first $10^6$ digits of $\pi$ is about $0.5$, but in fact one can check the digits of $\pi$ and deduce that probability to be either $0$ or $1$. Yet, sometimes that sort of speculation is helpful to decide our confidence in facts which are not easy to check.

Given that setting, for $r \geq p-1$ we can speculate that for $p\equiv \pm 2 \mod 5$ the element $v_{+}$ is one of $p^2$ possible elements of $\text{GF}(p)[\sqrt{5}]$, and $2p+2$ of them lie on the orbit of $u_{+}$. Thus, there is roughly $\frac{2p+2}{p^2} > \frac{1}{p}$ probability that $v_{+}$ lies on the orbit of $u_{+}$. For $p \equiv \pm 1 \mod 5$ two conditions need to hold: $u_{+}^m = v_{+}$ and $u_{-}^m = v_{-}$ for the same $m$. Under the assumption $r=p-1$ the first of them determines a unique $m$ unless $v_{+}=0$, hence we estimate the likelihood they both hold at the same time as $\frac{p-1}{p^2} = \frac{1}{p} + o(1)$. Assuming these likelihoods to be independent for different $p$ and denoting the density of the primes satisfying conjecture 1 as $C$ and using [the density of primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) we get

$$\left(\text{Likelihood of $M = \infty$}\right) \leq \prod_{p\in\text{Primes}\setminus\{2,5\}}\left(1-\frac{C(1+o(1))}{p}\right) \\
= \exp\left(-C\int_{5}^\infty \frac{1+o(1)}{n\ln(n)}dn\right) = 0,$$

because the integral in the exponent diverges. The divergence is slow (as $C\ln\ln n$), hence, although the above argument suggests that a prime $p$ s.t. $p\mid \widetilde d_n$ is very likely to exist, it could be very large. E.g. this argument suggests that if we know that there are no such $p < 10^6$, and $C=0.5$ then one would need to search up to $p \simeq 10^{2400}$ if we want the above bounds to "guarantee" a $95\%$ confidence to find such $p$. If we do a more careful estimate instead of the bounds, effective $C$ could be higher, putting an estimate at around $p\simeq 10^{120}$ ($\pm$ a few dozen orders of magnitude) to "guarantee" the same confidence. I don't know any feasible way to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for these nice heuristic arguments which once again recall the difficulty of making conjectures in number theory based on experimentation.

Comment: I think we can't do better